# How to sort query results by date then specific column values in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sql-order-by

I'm trying to sort my query results by date, then within each timeframe by if the status is 'sold', then if the status is 'contingent', then if the status is 'canceled'.  Nothing I do to the ORDER BY clause seems to work.  I would really appreciate some insight into what I'm doing wrong.  Here's my query as it is now:

```
            SELECT
                subdivision community
            ,  lot_number lot
            ,  homeowner buyer
            ,  agent_initials agent
            ,  date_sold date
            ,  sales.plan plan
            ,  sales.inv_pre type
            ,  sold_price price
            ,  'sold' status
            ,  SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(date_sold,'-',2),'-',-1) month

            FROM
                sales

            JOIN
                third_party_sources
                ON sales.job_id = third_party_sources.job_id

            WHERE
                sales.is_contingent is null
            AND sales.date_sold BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate
            OR  sales.is_contingent = 0
            AND sales.date_sold BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate

            UNION

            SELECT
                subdivision community
            ,  lot_number lot
            ,  homeowner buyer
            ,  agent_initials agent
            ,  date_sold date
            ,  sales.plan plan
            ,  sales.inv_pre type
            ,  sold_price price
            ,  'contingent' status
            ,  SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(date_sold,'-',2),'-',-1) month

            FROM
                sales

            JOIN
                third_party_sources
                ON sales.job_id = third_party_sources.job_id

            WHERE
                sales.is_contingent
            AND sales.date_sold BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate

            UNION

            SELECT
                subdivision community
            ,  lot_number lot
            ,  buyer_name buyer
            ,  agent_initials agent
            ,  date_canceled date
            ,  null plan
            ,  null type
            ,  null price
            ,  'canceled' status
            ,  SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(date_canceled,'-',2),'-',-1) month

            FROM
                cancellations

            JOIN
                third_party_sources
                ON cancellations.job_id = third_party_sources.job_id

            WHERE
                cancellations.date_cancelled BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate

            ORDER BY
                date
            ,  status = 'sold'
            ,  status = 'contingent'
            ,  status = 'canceled'
```

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want:

```
ORDER BY date, FIELD(status, 'sold', 'contingent', 'canceled')
```

This assumes that these are the only three values.  If there are more values, then your method would work . . . with `DESC`:

```
ORDER BY date, (status = 'sold') DESC, (status = 'contingent') DESC, (status = 'canceled') DESC
```